# How to set number of ticks along X axis in a boxplot in matlab?

Tags: matlab-figure, boxplot

I have created a boxplot with monthly data over a number of years. The result is bringing up far too many dates on the x axis to be able to read, so I want to be able to set it so that I can show every third or fourth date, or specify the number of dates shown.

I tried using the following:

```
NumTicks = 20;
L = get(gca,'XLim');
set(gca,'XTick',linspace(L(1),L(2),NumTicks))
```

But it appears that what this did was count the number of ticks (180), then use the first 180 dates in my data file to create the labels. As each box is created from 9 samples from each date, this has meant that instead of my date range being shown as 2004 - 2019, it comes up on the labels as 2004 - 2006.

Comment: I think you should dilute the ticks labels (see [`xticklabels`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xticklabels.html?s_tid=doc_ta)) with empty strings (`[]`) instead of diluting the ticks

Comment: How do I do that? I don't want to have to do it manually as I have over 1600 rows which equate to about 180 dates, and I add more every month

Comment: It will be much simpler to understand your problem if you attach an image with the current result, and explain what is the desired change in it. In principle, when the labels are not just the numbers on the axis, you need to specify both the ticks and the ticks labels, otherwise, the labels are replicated along the axis to fill all available ticks.